# How to replace identical positions in two different lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, programming, random

Assume that I have two lists like :

`list1={1,2,3,4,5};
list2={a,b,c,d,e};`

I want to replace some elements from `list1` into `list2` and make a new list, `NewList`. For example, I want to replace the elements of `list1` from position 1 and 5, with the elements of `list2` with the same positions. The result will be :

`NewList={1,b,c,d,5};`

Is there any way to do that ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way, doing it all at once:

```
Newlist = list2;    
Newlist[[{1,5}]] = list1[[{1,5}]];
```

Gives

```
Newlist
   (* {1, b, c, d, 5} *)
```

Comment: It's a nice and easy method! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e};

NewList = list2;
NewList[[1]] = list1[[1]];
NewList[[5]] = list1[[5]];
NewList
```

> {1, b, c, d, 5}

Answer (score 1):

```
Newlist = ReplacePart[#2, Rule @@@ Transpose[{#3, #1[[#3]]}]] &[list1, list2, {1, 5}]
```